# appcmd bugged with more than 70ish bindings?

Tags: iis-7

Can anyone help me with this? Or if anyone has a suggestion for a better method of getting a csv or some sort of output from a IIS7 server I am up for that.

Server: W2k8 R2, IIS 7.5

```
C:\Users\Administrator>%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd LIST SITES
SITE "Default Web Site" (id:1,bindings:http/*:80:,net.tcp/808:*,net.pipe/*,net.msmq/localhost,msmq.formatname/localhost,state:Started)
SITE "test3" (id:2,bindings:http/*:8088:,state:Stopped)
SITE "test4" (id:3,bindings:http/*:8099:,state:Stopped)
SITE "test5" (id:4,bindings:http/*:8055:,state:Stopped)
ERROR ( hresult:8007007a, message:Failed to generate item output.
The data area passed to a system call is too small.
 )
```

It seems if I have a lot of bindings (over 100 in this case) the appcmd fails, all i want for christmas is a list of my websites and their bindings.

I used a vbs script to get this info from IIS 6, but it does not work with IIS7

Many thanks all

PS I am not what you would call a good developer, so type slowly to me :)

Answer (score 2):

http://forums.iis.net/p/1164443/1932481.aspx

Summary: It turned out appcmd has buffer limit. The error happens when  has lots of data. It looks like there is no workaround with appcmd for that particular command. I would recommend to use other admin tool such as inetmgr with this situation. The feature team will address this issue.

A little late for Christmas, sorry.

**Edit: The solution I just came up with is a simple PowerShell script:**

```
import-module WebAdministration
get-website | select name,id,state, physicalpath,
@{n="Bindings"; e= { ($_.bindings | select -expa collection) -join ';' }} |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\my_list.csv
```

Taken from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126811/powershell-list-of-websites-using-get-website